# Is sending data using $_SESSION instead of $_POST a good thing?

Tags: php, post

I saw many , many questions about sending data using `$_POST` without form.

Let's say that we receive from another web (e.g. through their API) and the page that we told the API the return the data is `receive.php` and we want that data to be accessible from every page (data such as access token from user's facebook their public profile etc.)

Some of the answers said to use Ajax or jQuery to send a form (which I think it's going to slow down the receive.php page).

Some of them said that you can use `$_POST['foo'] = $foo` (which I tried, but it didn't work, it's also shouldn't)

Some of the answer say to use `$_SESSION` which I think it's making sense if it's session related thing such as user's token from facebook, but if it's something like their public profile and such won't use `$_SESSION` make no sense? and is it a good practice?

Comment: you can't send data using $_SESSION, period

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just saw some answer said that you can and it's bothering me

Comment: It sounds like you have some *serious* misunderstandings of how web applications interact and what HTTP requests, session state, and other web-development concepts are.  As a result, what you're asking makes almost no sense.  Maybe you have a specific example of something you attempted and would like to understand why it's not working as you expect?

Comment: I'm using facebook getSessionFromRedirect() and use loggedin.php as a return page from facebook. And I'm wondering if using $_SESSION to store data such as user's profile will be a good practice because I saw some answer said you can.

Comment: I don't think storing data in $_SESSION is a good practice by any mean, from what I'm understanding $_SESSION is designed to store "session".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is intended to store data in order to share it between different requests. `$_POST` is intended to send and receive data that won't be persisted between requests (unless the data is sent back and forth between those requests).